# Able to remove .php extension but can't index.php from php mvc url pattern

Tags: php, .htaccess, model-view-controller

I am able to remove **.php** from my URL but can't remove **index.php** in php mvc framework. Actually I need **/app/className/action** instead of **/index.php/app/className/action**.

My **.htaccess** file structure is bellow,

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

This rules return **/index/app/className/action** instead of **/app/className/action**.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To remove `index.php` ,you can use the following rules :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
  #Redirect /index.php/foobar to /foobar
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php/.+ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^index.php/(.+)$ /$1 [L,R]
   #internally map /foobar back to /index.php/foobar
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```